# Unable to call variable inside function in different script

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

Hey I am trying to make this work as, Once the GUI loads up I want to take a file input and say I store it in "X" which is also inside a function, Now I want to access this file value in another python script

I have tried inhertiance,importing function,script,objects.

Here's the Driver code:-

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import subprocess
global x
x=""
global e1
e1=""
window = tkinter.Tk()
class Driver:
        window.minsize(300,300)
        window.title("Extractor")
        e1 = None
        global showx
        def showx():

                x=e1.get()
                print x
#       def __init__(self):
#               self.x = x
        global callback
        def callback():
                global e1
                Label(window,text="File").pack()
                e1 = Entry(window)
                e1.insert(10,"Please input")
                e1.pack()
                process = tkinter.Button(window,text="GO",command=showx)
                process.pack()
                toplabel=tkinter.Label(window,text="Enumeration tool for PCAP")
        enum = tkinter.Button(window,text ="Enumerate",command=callback)
        enum.pack(side=TOP)
        def quit():
                window.destroy()
        quit=Button(window,text="Exit",command=quit)
        quit.pack(side=BOTTOM)
window.mainloop()
```

My Attempts:

```
root@karma:~/Desktop/IITK/Filter/GUI?# python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import GUI as obj
>>> obj.showx()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "GUI.py", line 13, in showx
    x=e1.get()
NameError: global name 'e1' is not defined
>>> obj.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> obj.showx()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "GUI.py", line 13, in showx

NameError: global name 'e1' is not defined
>>>
root@karma:~/Desktop/IITK/Filter/GUI?#
root@karma:~/Desktop/IITK/Filter/GUI?# python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import GUI as obj
>>> obj.showx()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "GUI.py", line 14, in showx
    x=e1.get()
NameError: global name 'e1' is not defined
>>> NameError: global name 'disp' is not defined
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    NameError: global name 'disp' is not defined
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
root@karma:~/Desktop/IITK/Filter/GUI?# python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import GUI as obj
>>> obj.showx()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "GUI.py", line 16, in showx
    x=e1.get()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
>>>
>>> obj.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you have executable code in your class that's not inside a method? It's possible to do that, but not recommended, unless you know what you're doing. And why are you trying to use `global` inside a class? You should be using attributes to store state information.

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you suggest something to read?

Comment: There are some good suggestions [here](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F). And take a look at the Tkinter code in answers here on Stack Overflow, especially runnable programs from people with high rep, since they usually post well-structured code.

Comment: @PM2Ring is there any way to access x via another class It'll be really helpful if you can suggest a way?

Comment: First, you need to study a bit more about classes in Python. And at this stage, I recommend you write your program as a single file, don't try to split it up over multiple files. As the error messages indicate, there are numerous problems with that code, apart from the issues I mentioned earlier. Eg, none of your methods have a `self` argument. And `global showx` and `global callback` don't make much sense. Also, although you've attempted to define the Driver class you haven't actually created an instance of it.

Comment: `from tkinter import *` means that you can leave off the `tkinter.` from `tkinter.Tk()`.

Comment: Don't use `from tkinter import *`, it may cause name conflicts. Instead, use `import tkinter as tk`, it is the most used way to import tkinter and everyone understands `tk` means `tkinter` instead of other names.